# constructing variable name from a variable in c++

Tags: c++

I have lots of arrays with different sizes so they can't be multidimensional array as far as i know, so i named them as follows:

```
arr1[]
arr2[]
arr3[]
arr4[]
...
```

now can i use for loop to go over them and access them...

```
for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    for(int j=o; i<etc; j++) {
     cout<<arr[i][[j]<<endl;
    }
}
or cout<<arr+i<<endl;
```

now this obviously is telling compiler to add arr and i together, but that is not what i want. I want it to print arr1, arr2, etc.

I have tried, putting dot, comma, slashes, etc.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` ?

Comment: because using array is the requirment, however, is it possible to put all arrays of different sizes into vector

Comment: Yes, you can put arrays in arrays by heap allocating them and using pointers

Comment: can you give some example

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - `because using array is the requirment,`  You do know that `vector` uses a dynamic array internally, right?  The internal array can be accessed very easily.   So what's the actual reason why you can't use vector?

Answer (score 4):

**No.** You *do* need an array here. More specifically, you need a heterogenous container.

With the magic of indirection, you can actually use a homogenous container at the C++ level to achieve these semantics:

```
std::vector<std::vector<WhateverYourTypeIs>> v;
```

If you really need only five in the outer array, this will do the job:

```
std::array<std::vector<WhateverYourTypeIs>, 5> a;
```

and will simplify your code.

Comment: @Galik: Right, and the OP said "I have lots of arrays with different sizes". That means different types. Granted, now that I'm introducing indirection (via `vector`) I suppose it's not really heterogenous any more, in the strictest sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you are really forced to use plain arrays (and only then), consider using an array of pointers too:

```
int* const array[] = {arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, ...};
```

Thus, you get a pointer to the first element of array `arr#` with `array+#`.

You might want a companion-array storing the element counts, too:

```
size_t carray[] = {sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr1, sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr2,
    sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr3, sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr4, ...};
```

Also, [look at this for a safer way to get the element-count of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4839626):

```
template<size_t N, class T>
constexpr size_t element_count(T (&arr)[N])
{return N;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing compile/build time and runtime. I would suppose to use only runtime objects like arrays/vectors.

But you could also use macros or variable argument lists:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html