# How to get amount of elements to an integer array in c++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, int

I want to get the amount of how much elements in an int array; for example, Here's a simple array of integer type:

`int myArray[] = {2, 4, 2, 13}` .

And I need to get the amount of elements ( here is `4` ). Please help me.

Comment: `const int myArrayLen = 4;`

Comment: I want to get ( not set). @StoryTeller

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839626/element-count-of-an-array-in-c

Comment: std::distance(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray) );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has not *decayed* into a pointer type, then you can use

`sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0])`

to yield the number of elements.

If you've passed `myArray` into a *function* though, you can't use this method. In that case the normal thing to do is to pass the size as an additional parameter.

Alternatively, in C++, use `std::vector<int>`.