# Is there a way in C++ to use a key word to determine array length?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make a function in C++ that will take a string input and use it to populate an array. The values that the array will be populated with are fixed, but it depends on the word passed in. Some of the elements stay the same, and some of them change. The array size is also dependent on the string that is passed in. I know I can do this by making two longer 'if' statements, but this method seems more efficent... if I can get it working. The code below is non-functioning, but it just to give a general idea of my headspace. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
myString = "long";
    
if (myString == "short") {
      int numArr* = new int[3];
      numArr[2] = 0x02;
      }
    
if (myString == "long") {
  int numArr* = new int[5];
  numArr[2] = 0x04;
  numArr[4] = 0xA1;
  numArr[5] = 0x32;
  }
  
numArr[0] = 0x00;
numArr[1] = 0xFF;
numArr[3] = 0x50;

cout << numArr;

delete[] numArr;
```

Comment: What C++ version are you using? Also populating `numArr[3]` unconditionally is accessing `new int[3]` out of bounds when `myString` is `"short"`

Comment: What is the reason you're not just using `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'key word'?

Comment: You have multiple issues with your code. But you said `not working` and didn't define what you meant by that. Anyhow, your issue is scoping. You're declaring `numArr` inside a scope, and trying to `cout` it outside of that scope. You need to take the `int nmArr*` and put it right after `myString = "long";`

Answer (score 2):

First, to answer your question:  Given a pointer-to-int (like `numArr` in your posted code), there is no portable way to query the size of the array that it points to (or even to verify that it actually points to an array at all!)

If you have a proper array, like this (not just a pointer), OTOH:

```
int properArray[6];
```

... a function like this will return the number of items in the array:

```
template<typename T, int size> constexpr unsigned int GetArraySize(T(&)[size]) 
{
   return size;
}

unsigned int arraySize = GetArraySize(properArray);  // sets arraySize to 6
```

That said, it seems to me the best way to make your code simpler and more efficient is to allocate a fixed-size array on the stack (large enough to handle your worst-case-scenario) and keep track of how many items in the array are actually being used, like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
   int numArr[6] = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00};
   int numValidArrayItems = 3;

   std::string myString = "long";
   if (myString == "short") {
     numArr[2] = 0x02;
   }
   else if (myString == "long") {
     numArr[2] = 0x04;
     numArr[4] = 0xA1;
     numArr[5] = 0x32;
     numValidArrayItems = 6;
   }

   for (int i=0; i<numValidArrayItems; i++) std::cout << numArr[i] << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

That avoids the `new` and `delete[]` calls, which are likely to be the most expensive (and error-prone) parts of the posted code, and also avoids the need to query the `numArr` pointer to determine the size of the array it is pointing to.

Comment: something is weird about the types involved in your template: the template parameter type is an (signed) `int` int, the return type of the function is `unsigned int`. Both should match though and it would be preferrable to use `size_t`: `template<typename T, size_t> constexpr size_t GetArraySize...`

Comment: If you have C++17 or later, there's no need to write your own `GetArraySize` one is included: `std::size(properArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int r[10];
int count = sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]);
cout<<count;
```

I saw only this type of solution, sorry. You can look at this thread and get better insight(if you wan to use function, for example)

Link for mentioned thread:
[Element count of an array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839626/element-count-of-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Unfortunately this technique doesn't work with *dynamic* arrays created with `new`.

Comment: If you note in the question `numArry` is declared as a pointer (`int numArr*`) so `sizeof numArr;` is `sizeof (a_pointer);` -- not what you want. (if used with the pointer in the question `count == 1` if `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(a_pointer)` are the same or likely `2` where you have a 4-byte `int` and 8-byte pointer).